# $W(A)=\{x^HAx : x^Hx=1,{x\in \mathbb{C}}\}$, ${A\in \mathbb{R}}^{n\cdot n}$ How do I show that set is symmetrical set regard to real axis?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I need help to solve this task, so I would accept any suggestion: If  ${A\in \mathbb{R}}^{n\cdot n}$, show that set  $W(A)=\{x^HAx : x^Hx=1,\,{x\in \mathbb{C^n}}\}$,  is a symmetrical set with respect to the real axis?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** What happens if you replace $x^H A x$ with $\bar{x}^H A \bar{x}$? Here $\bar{x}$ denotes the vector whose entries are the complex conjugates of those in $x$.

Comment: What if set of solutions is above the real axis,then I have only complex numbers and no their conjugates? In that case matrix A can't be real?

Comment: Correct. One such example of that would be $n = 1$ and $A = (i)$. In this case, if $x = (z)$, then $x^HAx = i x^H x = i$.